# Need COUNT from a more complex query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, count

I usually use COUNT within a subquery to grab the desired number, but in this case I need a little help as the query contains too many arguments.

```
SELECT a.[QueueID]
  ,a.[CouponID]
  ,a.[ListingID]
  ,a.[User_ID]
  ,b.[CouponID]
  ,b.[ListingID]
  ,b.[CouponActive] 
  ,b.[CouponExpire] 
  ,b.[IsDeleted]
  ,c.[ListingID]
  ,c.[TypeID]
  ,c.[LevelID]
  ,@passedUserID as User_ID

FROM CouponQueue a
JOIN Coupon b
    on a.CouponID = b.CouponID
JOIN Listing c
    on b.ListingID = c.ListingID

WHERE (a.[User_ID] = @passedUserID)
AND (b.[CouponActive] = 1)
AND (b.[IsDeleted] = 0)
AND (b.[CouponExpire] > DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()) OR b.[CouponExpire] IS NULL)
```

So lets say this query returns a result of 7 rows. All I need is this number for my VIEW. So I want to limit the ultimate result to a single row so that in the end I get:

```
[TotalCount] <-- Field name
[7] <-- Result
```

But not 7 rows of data.. I just need the count from the above query. Still plugging away and trying to learn. I looked at a few other examples but I haven't found one with all the conditions... which is what's messing me up.  Please help!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
select count(*) as TotalCOunt from (
SELECT a.[QueueID] /* 
  ,a.[CouponID]
  ,a.[ListingID]
  ,a.[User_ID]
  ,b.[CouponID]
  ,b.[ListingID]
  ,b.[CouponActive] 
  ,b.[CouponExpire] 
  ,b.[IsDeleted]
  ,c.[ListingID]
  ,c.[TypeID]
  ,c.[LevelID]
  ,@passedUserID as User_ID */

FROM CouponQueue a
JOIN Coupon b
    on a.CouponID = b.CouponID
JOIN Listing c
    on b.ListingID = c.ListingID

WHERE (a.[User_ID] = @passedUserID)
AND (b.[CouponActive] = 1)
AND (b.[IsDeleted] = 0)
AND (b.[CouponExpire] > DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()) OR b.[CouponExpire] IS NULL)
) t
```

You can remove the columns for the count.  They are not actually necessary.

Comment: Hi Gordon!!! You saved my butt last time! Too funny. Good to see you again. I got the following error from your suggestions: The column 'CouponID' was specified multiple times for 't'.

Comment: You can just remove all the columns for the count.  They are not actually necessary.

Comment: Thank you again Gordon! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to just add COUNT(*):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalCount    
FROM CouponQueue a
JOIN Coupon b
    on a.CouponID = b.CouponID
JOIN Listing c
    on b.ListingID = c.ListingID
WHERE (a.[User_ID] = @passedUserID)
AND (b.[CouponActive] = 1)
AND (b.[IsDeleted] = 0)
AND (b.[CouponExpire] > DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()) OR b.[CouponExpire] IS NULL)
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the below sample on your SQL Developer to run for the count:

```
SELECT count(*) as totalCount (*-open a parentheses - your original query -close the parentheses*)
```